# Texture mapping, object maps to 1 pixel

Tags: uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor, texture-paint-mode

I'm trying to add/paint a texture map to an object, and when I do, I'm unable to draw anything because the object seems to map to just 1 pixel on my texture image.

Here you can see that the white doesn't go onto the object.
[image]

If I try to paint in the right window directly onto the object, it changes the entire color of the object and seems to map to just the bottom left pixel.
[image]

Here is my shading window, it's not all that complicated so I'm really confused as to why it's not mapping normally by default. How do I fix it to behave normally? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is it UV mapped?

Comment: I assume it is, I should've mentioned I'm a blender noob, and the only other thing I've created is a donut with the blender guru tutorial.

Comment: Then you probably need to uv map it.  There are plenty of tutorials available; to get started, enter edit, select all, numpad 7 for top view, and u->project from view (bounds).